# Styling not loading when implemented on server

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, webserver, yesod

When running my website locally (via `yesod devel`) the styling loads up and all is good.
CSS files are loaded correctly. Using this [method](http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2013/01/adding-css-js)

But when uploaded onto my amazon ec2 server styling is not loaded correctly.

I'm using nginx that listens to port 80, then redirects it to port 3000 where my yesod webapp is running.  My nginx.conf settings.

[image]

So I can directly got to [header.css](http://www.finance-web.biz/static/css/header.css) showing that the static files are passed on to the user browser.  However, for some reason the css is not connecting correctly.

Another thing I've noticed is that if I directly go to the IP and port 3000, the default `favicon.ico` icon will get loading, whereas if I go to the domain it will not get loaded.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the *approot* setting in *config/settings.yml* agree with the start of the url you were using to access the ec2 server?  The log you show could certainly be explained by it being wrong.  Yesod builds in fully qualified urls, using the *approot* as the prefix, for all of the additional pieces needed to build up a page.  (Check the page source to see what Yesod has produced.)

If you are running using *yesod devel* for now, the *approot* setting will be the one set for the "Development" environment - which will be the one in the "Defaults" section if you have kept the structure of *settings.yml* as it was when you created your scaffolded site.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed the config/setting.yml but still not working.

Comment: It looks as if either the style sheet url in the page is still wrong, or access to it is not being forwarded by your front end server.  I would start from the page source, and follow the style sheet url by hand to debug it!

Answer (score 0):

Found nothing seriously wrong on your nginx.conf file.

I hit http://www.finance-web.biz/static/css/header.css and the result is fine.

```
/*!
 * Extra header style
 */

.beta {
    color: #CC3300;
}
```

Maybe it's something cached in your browser.